# how to integrate evo-calendar with node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, calendar

How to integrate the evo-calendar[https://edlynvillegas.github.io/evo-calendar/] with node.js and mongodb?
I read each and every documentation
About it but I didn't found anything.It seems silly question.But I am beginner with this, someone help me.thanks in advance.sorry for my poor English

Comment: Please show us what your efforts that you have done and tell us any errors/problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Evo Calendar homepage](https://edlynvillegas.github.io/evo-calendar/) and the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/edlynvillegas/evo-calendar), all the docs refer to front-end only. This means that the part where data is written and retrieved from database is not included and you'd have to write it yourself. It makes sense for the project to handle the calendar data visual representation only, since there are dozens of scenarios, how the calendar data can be stored.
So, to move on with this, you'd need to write additional functions or methods to get the calendar working with back-end, think AJAX.